# Cómo editar registro que contiene un select

Tags: laravel, select

Estoy comenzando a trabajar con Laravel 5.8. y aunque voy avanzando con buen paso hay cuestiones que no llego a controlar por lo que os pido ayuda para ver si alguién me puede indicar con debe hacerse.

Estoy desarrollando un CRUD que entre otras muchas relaciones y tablas tiene una tabla de categorías y otra de subcategorías con relación 1:N.

Cuándo doy de alta una nueva subcategoría en el formulario correspondiente, tengo un select en el que indico la categoría a la que pertenece la cuál almacena en la tabla subcategorías el id correspondiente a la categoría seleccionada.

Mi problema viene cuando quiero editar dicho registro. ¿Cómo debo hacer para que al editar el registro el select muestre seleccionado la categoría a la que pertenece dicha subcategoría.

Espero haberme explicado con claridad.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano a todos.

Comment: Usas Laravel Collective o Html para los inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu controlador debes enviar a la vista el modelo que quieres editar y todas las categorías

```
public function edit($id)
{
    return view('vista')->with([
        'modelo' => Modelo::find($id),
        'categorias' => Categoria::all()
    ]);
}
```

y en la vista debes hacer un formulario parecido al de crear

```
<form action="{{route('modelo.update', $modelo)}}">
    @csrf
    ....
    <select>
        @foreach($categorias as $categoria)
        <option value="{{$categoria->id}}" {{($categoria->id == $modelo->categoria_id)?'selected':''}}>{{$categoria->categoria}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Buenas noches Fabián. Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Me has resuelto la duda de como gestionar un select en la edición de un registro. Un saludo.